# Capture mono-service stdout console output?

Tags: mono-service

Starting a service like this say:

```
mono-service2 myservice.exe -l:/var/run/test
```

How does one capture stdout?  How does one capture the output if it crashes?

Aside from the program logging itself, the output seems to be lost.  syslog seems to only contain information re: mono-service2, not the assembly it's running: myservice.exe.

Answer (score 3):

The --debug option will give you the stdout for it, you should be able to redirect it to a file:

```
mono-service2 myservice.exe -l:/var/run/test --debug > log.txt
```